# Using npm to install grunt on nodeenv results in findup-sync error

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

After establishing a node virtualenv using nodeenv, I use source /bin/activate
to switch into the correct directory, update npm, and execute

`npm install -g grunt` or `npm install -g grunt-cli` and I recieve the same error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-53-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/{redacted-home-dir}/NodeProjects/vue/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.1
npm ERR! file /home/{redacted-home-dir}/.npm/findup-sync/0.1.3/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: /home/{redacted-home-dir}/.npm/findup-sync/0.1.3/package/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/{redacted-home-dir}/NodeProjects/vue/npm-debug.log
```

[A similar error](https://github.com/cowboy/node-findup-sync/issues/7) was noted on the findup-sync Github, but this the most recent edition of npm.

Grunt's [package.json](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/package.json) says "approximately 0.1.2" according to the npm docs.

I also have tried installing findup-sync independently, to no avail.

Other details about my computer: Linux (Debian/Ubuntu 14.04). 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have maybe a corrupted cache : `npm cache clean`

Comment: I downloaded the package and i have the same npm, the package.json is right. The only time i got this kind of error was after a `npm install` got killed while writing a file, so the only solution to that is to clear the files, the cache in his case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I would have never have thought of this because I'm quite new to the Node.js universe.